# Rails 6 form_with will not pass resources with Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using Rails 6. I have a form that I need to pass `remote: true` so I get POST to process as  JS:

`LOG:  MessagesController#create as JS`

Here is what I have tried:

`<%= form_for [@hangout, Message.new] do |f| %>`

The result is a good save to the DB but processes as HTML:

`LOG:  MessagesController#create as HTML`

So I tried:

`<%= form_for [@hangout, Message.new], remote: true do |f| %>`

I learned that this would give an InvalidAuthenticityToken error:

`LOG:  ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken - ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken:`

Tried this:

`<%= form_for [@hangout, Message.new], authenticity_token: true  do |f| %>`

It passes as HTML, not JS

I read that for Rails 6, the best way to do this was with form_with because it passes `remote:true`:

`<%= form_with(model: [@hangout, Message.new]) do |f| %>`

Unfortunately, this never reaches the controller so I get no response.  I know that my model and controller are set up properly since the first try with form_for works, so it has to be with the way I am writing my form_with, right?

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

```
#model
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hangout
  belongs_to :user
end

#controller
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_hangout
  def create
    message = @hangout.messages.new(message_params)
    message.user = current_user
    message.save
    redirect_to @hangout
  end
  private
    def set_hangout
      @hangout = Hangout.find(params[:hangout_id])
    end
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:body)
    end
end

#routes
require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :hangouts do
    resource :hangout_users
    resources :messages
  end

  resources :notes

  authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }

  get 'mine', to: 'notes#mine'

  root to: 'application#root'

  mount Shrine.presign_endpoint(:cache) => '/images/upload'
end

# application.js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require('stylesheets/application.scss')
require('jquery')
require("packs/notes")
require("packs/hangouts")
window.Jquery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

UPDATE

I made progress but not quite there. I’m correctly posting to the DB with the proper entry but there is no redirect to the hangouts#show page. Create.js.erb is rendered instead:

```
Form: 
<%= form_for [@hangout, Message.new], 
  remote: true, authenticity_token: true, 
  format: :js  do |f| %>

Controller: 
def create    
  @message =  @hangout.messages.build(message_params)
  @message.user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
        if @message.save
          format.js
          format.html { redirect_to @hangout, notice: 'Success' }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
   end
  end
 end
LOG: Processing by MessagesController#create as JS
```

But now create.js.erb is rendered when hangouts#show should be rendered:

```
views/messages/create.js.erb
 $("#new_message")[0].reset();

Rendered in the browser:
/hangouts/1/messages.js$("#message_body")[0].reset();
```

Any thought?

Comment: share your `application.js` content

Comment: Thanks. I updated the original post

Comment: It seems issue with js as your request is not submitted as ajax. Do you see any error in browser console or any error in webpacker compilation?

Comment: @AmitPatel, see my update above.  Thanks!

Comment: You form is submitted via ajax and so `format.js` handler will render `create.js`. In ajax, you cannot redirect. Instead, write `window.location = '/your/path/to/show'` in create.js which then will redirect.

Comment: @AmitPatel, its still rendering create.js as text in the browser.
10.0.0.1:3000/hangouts/1/messages.js
window.location = 'hangouts/show'

What do you think if js is rendering as text?